# How can I set an AAD group as an owner on an AAD application?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm provisioning a bunch of Azure Active Directory (AAD) apps, and would like the same set of users to be owners on all apps.  I created an AAD group to put those users in, but when I tried to assign the group as the owner, I get an error:

```
> Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RefObjectId $ownershipGroup.ObjectId
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner : Error occurred while executing AddApplicationOwner 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The reference target 'Group_<mygroupid>' of type 'Group' is invalid for the 'owners' reference.
```

Is my scenario not a supported one, or am I simply trying to do it in the wrong way?  I'm not sure whether the error message is meant to be read as "reference target  - which happens to be a group - is invalid" or "reference target is invalid because it's a group".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the official definition, the **owners** are a set of non-admin users who are allowed to modify this object.

If a request for a property that is not valid for a specific entity is sent, a 400 Bad Request response is returned.

Therefore, I think the owners currently only support for **Users**.

More information about properties for application entity, please see the article below.

[Entity and complex type reference | Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#directoryobject-entity)

The feature requirement for supporting Azure AD group in application owner, has already been submitted in user voice website below.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6688284-ad-groups-in-application-owners

Comment: The feature request has been submitted in the user voice website, you can take a vote for that. Please find the link in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

As this point in time, **only Users can be assigned as application owners**.

I'd recommend you add an entry in the [Azure AD UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) forum to request this feature.